# Counting number of lines and characters from StdIn

Tags: java

I want to put something into StdIn while running this code, such as a line of text. The code should print out the number of lines, characters, and words in the text string. I currently am able to figure out the number of characters and words but I am having trouble with finding the number of lines. How can I implement that here?

```
public class WordCount
{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int words = 0, lines = 0, characters = 0;
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String word = StdIn.readString();
            characters += word.length();
            words++;
        }
        StdOut.println("There are " + words + "words");
        StdOut.println("There are " + characters + "characters");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `StdIn` and content of `StdIn.readString();` method.

Comment: @Tom StdIn is a library from [this website](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/). There are 4 programs needed to be downloaded, since they interlock with each other in a way.

Comment: After looking at the library you have mentioned above, Why don't you try using `Scanner` class. It provides all the wrapper methods for reading inputs from `STDIN`. [Scanning and Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanfor.html).

Comment: @YoungHobbit Scanner was what I used before I was introduced to Stdin and stdout etc. i'd like to solve this program with stdin

Comment: @Atri `%java WordCount I like to eat food ^Z` in the command prompt

Comment: What is the line separator that you are using? How will you determine if there are multiple lines in your input?

Comment: Use `StdIn.readLine()` instead of `StdIn.readString()` and I leave the rest to you ... it's quite easy to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/), you can use the method `readLine()` instead of `readString()`. That way you can get the count of lines easily. After you get the line, you can split it on space and count the number of words. Loop through each of the word to get the character count.

```
public class WordCount
{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int words = 0, lines = 0, characters = 0;
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String line = StdIn.readLine();
            lines++;
            String[] lineWords = line.split("\\s+");
            words += lineWords.length;
            for(String word : lineWords)
                characters += word.length();
        }
        StdOut.println("There are " + lines + "lines");
        StdOut.println("There are " + words + "words");
        StdOut.println("There are " + characters + "characters");
    }
}
```